# how does ElasticSearch store _source field and other meta fields

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Couple questions about ES index structure please:

(1) Is _source a field in Lucene, if so, how does Lucene store it, would it be a Key-Value store rather than inverted index.

(2) Is ES _id a field in Lucene, or it's in other Key-Value storage. If I use md5 as my doc's id and also create md5 field in my doc, which one query would be faster, i.e search _id or search md5 faster?

(3) Is ES _type a field in Lucene, if so, why different _type in ES can have the same doc _id.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The [`_source` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) which contains the original JSON is stored so it can be fetched (via [get requests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#_source), [scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_source_field), etc). However, it is **not indexed**, and thus not searchable.

(3) Each document has a [`_type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-type-field.html) and an [`_id`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) field. Both together form the [`_uid` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-uid-field.html) whose value is `{type}#{id}`. Both the `_uid` and the `_type` fields **are indexed** and can be used in queries, aggregations, scripts and sorting. The `_uid` field is also the reason why the same `_id` can be used in different `_type` (i.e. `_uid` will always be unique). However, the `_id` field is **not indexed** as its value can be derived from the `_uid` field.

(2) You can retrieve a document [by its `_id`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html) and that will always be faster than searching the document via any other field, whether that field is MD5 or not. It is also worth noting, though, that before ES 2.0, it was important to [cleverly pick the right IDs](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html) for your documents. As of 2.0, it has become [less of a concern](https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-indexing-2.0) and you can pick whatever ID you like.